# Auth0: How can I get all scopes in rule?

Tags: auth0, scopes

I have create some test-api in Auth0 and added some scopes to there, like "read:users, create:users" and else. When I create some rule for this api, I want to obtain in this rule all list of scopes, which I have added.
[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFnRv.jpg)

Is it possible?